# Describing Function for non-symmetric Saturation Model

Tags: signal-analysis, control-systems

Let's talk about a standard saturation model:

[image]

with bounds $bound_{lower}$ and $bound_{upper}$. So in this example the output $y$ will be:

\begin{equation} 
 y(u) = 
 \begin{cases}
     bound_{lower} & u < bound_{lower} \\
        u             & bound_{lower} \leqslant u \leqslant bound_{upper} \\
        bound_{upper} & u > bound_{upper} \\
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

We can use a describing function to describe the magnitude of such nonlinear system.

For a symmetric saturation model (i.e. the $bound_{lower} = -\delta$ and $bound_{uppwer} = \delta$  for some given constant $\delta$), the describing function, $N(a)$ for it is simple:

\begin{equation} 
 N(a) = 
 \begin{cases}
     1 &a \leqslant \delta \\
     \frac{1}{\pi}(2\alpha + \sin(2\alpha)) \quad &a > \delta
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\alpha = \arcsin(\delta/a)$.

But what is a describing function for a non-symmetric saturation model? In this case, $bound_{lower} = \delta_1$ and $bound_{uppwer} = \delta_2$ with $\delta_2 > \delta_1$.

More specifically, the case I am interested is for the case of $\delta_1 = 0$ and $\delta_2$ being some positive value.

Comment: What kind of model is this? How do you get from the two bounds to the given equation with the sines? That step is not obvious to me. Is this a special model in a certain field? If so, please elaborate.

Comment: No no, this is a standard saturation model. I'll edit my question to give more detail

Comment: I guess you just need to compute the Fourier series (or even only the first coefficient) of an asymmetrically clipped sinusoid.

Answer (score 0):

The type of describing function $N(A)$ that you mention in your question describes the behavior of a (memoryless) non-linear system when excited by a sinusoidal input signal $x(t)=A\sin(\omega_0t)$. The describing function neglects all harmonics above the fundamental and the output signal is represented as

$$y(t)=|N(A)|A\sin(\omega_0t+\phi_N(A))\tag{1}$$

where $\phi_N(A)=\arg\{N(A)\}$ ($N(A)$ is generally complex-valued). Note that (1) resembles the output of a linear time-invariant system with 'transfer function' $N(A)$, the only important difference being that this 'transfer function' depends on the amplitude of the input signal, which of course can't be the case for a linear system.

If we write the output signal as a Fourier series

$$y(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_ne^{jn\omega_0t}$$

with the complex Fourier coefficients given by

$$c_n=\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}y(t)e^{-jn\omega_0t}dt,\quad\quad T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega_0}\tag{2}$$

and if we neglect all terms with $|n|>1$ we get

$$y(t)\approx c_0+2\text{Re}\{c_1 e^{j\omega_0t}\}=c_0+2|c_1|\cos(\omega_0t+\phi_1)=\\=c_0+2|c_1|\sin(\omega_0t+\phi_1+\pi/2),\quad\phi_1=\arg\{c_1\}\tag{3}$$

Comparing (3) to (1) we get

$$N(A)=\frac{2jc_1}{A}\tag{4}$$

So in order to compute the describing function $N(A)$ we just need to compute the complex Fourier coefficient $c_1$ of the output of the non-linear system when the input signal is $x(t)=A\sin(\omega_0t)$.

Evaluating (2) for the output signal of an asymmetrical clipper with upper limit $\delta_u$ and lower limit $-\delta_l$, we get

$$c_1=-\frac{jA}{2\pi}\left[\sin(\alpha+\beta)\cos(\alpha-\beta)+(\alpha+\beta)\right]$$

with $\alpha=\arcsin(\delta_u/A)$ and $\beta=\arcsin(\delta_l/A)$. From (4), the corresponding describing function is

$$N(A)=\frac{1}{\pi}\left[\sin(\alpha+\beta)\cos(\alpha-\beta)+(\alpha+\beta)\right]\tag{5}$$

which for $\alpha=\beta$ (i.e. for symmetrical clipping with $\delta_u=\delta_l$) is equal to the describing function in your question. Note that for asymmetrical clipping the describing function does not completely describe the output $y(t)$ because there is a non-zero DC component $c_0$ which must be added (cf. Eq. (3)).